# I need to convert a part of HTML page and part of data from java to a single PDF for production.How it can be achieved?

Tags: java, html, pdf, pdf-generation

For Example: I have a page containing image and the some data from DB.From these two data available i want to create a PDF document.What is the best solution?

Comment: I have used com.itextpdf in the past.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker thanks.I am analyzing  it

Comment: This effectively is asking us to recommend libraries to use as the functionality is not part of the core Java classes. Such questions are off topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jsPDF from Parallax, very simple to generate PDF.

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: Thanks.But i am searching for solution in java

Answer (score 0):

You Can try with iText 7, where we can define sctions like header, footer, images, css files.....

below are the sample code available in Itext

```
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.Event;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.IEventHandler;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.xobject.PdfFormXObject;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Canvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKey;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class pdfHTMLHeaderAndFooterExample {

    public static final String sourceFolder = "src/test/resources/pdfHTML/";
    public static final String destinationFolder = "target/output/pdfHTML/";
    public static final String LICENSE = "src/test/resources/pdfHTML/itextkey_trial.xml";

    public static final String[] files = {"ipsum"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(LICENSE);
        for (String name : files) {
            String htmlSource = sourceFolder + name + ".html";
            String resourceFolder = sourceFolder + name + "/";
            String pdfDest = destinationFolder + name + ".pdf";
            File file = new File(pdfDest);

            System.out.println("Parsing: " + htmlSource);
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            new pdfHTMLHeaderAndFooterExample().parseWithHeaderAndFooter(htmlSource, pdfDest, resourceFolder);

        }
    }

    public void parseWithHeaderAndFooter(String htmlSource, String pdfDest, String resoureLoc) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File pdf = new File(pdfDest);
        pdf.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        //Create Document
        PdfWriter writer= new PdfWriter(pdfDest);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        //Create event-handlers
        String header = "pdfHtml Header and footer example using page-events";
        Header headerHandler = new Header(header);
        PageXofY footerHandler = new PageXofY(pdfDocument);

        //Assign event-handlers
        pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE,headerHandler);
        pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE,footerHandler);

        //Convert
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(resoureLoc);
        HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdfDocument, converterProperties);
        //Write the total number of pages to the placeholder
        footerHandler.writeTotal(pdfDocument);
        pdfDocument.close();


    }

    //Header event handler
    protected class Header implements IEventHandler {
        String header;
        public Header(String header) {
            this.header = header;
        }
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            //Retrieve document and
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
            PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
            PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
            Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
            PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
                    page.getLastContentStream(), page.getResources(), pdf);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
            canvas.setFontSize(18f);
            //Write text at position
            canvas.showTextAligned(header,
                    pageSize.getWidth() / 2,
                    pageSize.getTop() - 30, TextAlignment.CENTER);
        }
    }

    //page X of Y 
    protected class PageXofY implements IEventHandler {
        protected PdfFormXObject placeholder;
        protected float side = 20;
        protected float x = 300;
        protected float y = 25;
        protected float space = 4.5f;
        protected float descent = 3;
        public PageXofY(PdfDocument pdf) {
            placeholder =
                    new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, side, side));
        }
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
            PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
            PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
            int pageNumber = pdf.getPageNumber(page);
            Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
            PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
                    page.getLastContentStream(), page.getResources(), pdf);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
                    .add("Page ").add(String.valueOf(pageNumber)).add(" of");
            canvas.showTextAligned(p, x, y, TextAlignment.RIGHT);
            pdfCanvas.addXObject(placeholder, x + space, y - descent);
            pdfCanvas.release();
        }
        public void writeTotal(PdfDocument pdf) {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdf);
            canvas.showTextAligned(String.valueOf(pdf.getNumberOfPages()),
                    0, descent, TextAlignment.LEFT);
        }
    }



}
```